# How to set SWT button foreground color?

Tags: java, colors, swt

The SWT Button class has a `setForeground(Color)` method but it seems to have no effect (the method is actually on Button's superclass). The javadoc says that this method is a hint and may be overridden by the platform. My platform is Windows.

- Does this mean that it is not possible to set button foreground color on Windows?
- Does it work on other platforms?
- Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, `setForeground` for `Buttons` has no effects.

As a workaround, add a `PaintListener` to your `Button`. On this Listener's `paintControl` method, get the generated event's `GC` and, with it, re-write the text of your `Button` using the color you want.

You can, in fact, draw anything over your `Button`.

Comment: @Kevin Stembridge
I'm new to SWT GC, can you help me out with how to get the positioning correct? It seems tricky because the text can be aligned differently. Thanks!

Comment: Positioning can be done via getSize() method of the Button and stringExtent() method of GC. So you can obtain the size of the button and size of the text.

Answer (score 2):

If you need Button with style SWT.CHECK you can try use Button without text and add Label element. Example:

```
chkAutorun = new Button(fCompositeLogin, SWT.CHECK);
Label lblAutorun = new Label(fCompositeLogin, SWT.NONE);
lblAutorun.setForeground(white);
lblAutorun.setText("Autorun");
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, setForeground doesn't work for Group either.

If you can convince your users to use the Classic Theme, setForeground will miraculously work.

Answer (score 0):

***This is the code to Implement FOreground Color in Buttons in SWT with allowing Mnemonic key to be Shown also and Enabled by Pressing Alt+"Mnemonic Key";***

```
Button radioButton=new Button(parent,SWT.RADIO);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("I am a Coloured radio button");
String name=null;
 String S = "I am a Coloured radio button";
String substr="C";
int i=S.indexOf(substr);
sb.insert(i,"&");
S=sb.toString();
name=sb.substring(i, i+2);
name=sb.toString();
String whiteSpace=" ";
final String TName=S;

for(int l=0;l<1000;l++)
    whiteSpace=whiteSpace.concat("            ");

radioButton.setText(name+whiteSpace);

radioButton.addPaintListener(new PaintListener(){
 String name=TName;
    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        e.gc.setForeground(hex2Col("ffffcc"));
        int x=21;
        int y=21;
        e.gc.drawText(name, x,y,SWT.DRAW_MNEMONIC | SWT.TRANSPARENT);

    }

});
```

**Note: hex2Col is my own method to Convert hex Color Code to Color Type**

**Note: Here ALT+C is Mnemonic Key Combination i have Used**