# Set SWT Check/Radio Button Foreground color in Windows

Tags: windows, swt

This is not a duplicate of [How to set SWT button foreground color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747562/how-to-set-swt-button-foreground-color/6704096#6704096). It's more like a follow up. I wrote follow-up questions as comments, but did not get any responses, so I thought I'd try to put it up as a question, and hopefully some expert will see it.

As is pointed in the referenced question, windows native button widgets do not support setting the foreground color (in fact, after more further research (more like experiments), it's been revealed that setForeground() works under the Classic Theme, but not others).

The answer/suggestion given in the referenced question is a good one (a.k.a providing a paint listener and drawing over the text with the correct color). I gave it a whirl but ran into a world of problems trying to decide the coordinate at which to draw the text:

It appears that - in addition to SWT attributes like alignment etc. - Windows has some rather hard-to-figure-out rule of deciding the location of the text. What makes it worse is that the location appears to be dependent on the windows theme in effect. Since I need to draw the text exactly over the natively-drawn windows text in order to override the color, this is a huge problem.

Please, can someone provide some much-needed help here? It'd be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to implement it as a custom Composite with a checkbox/radio button and a label. Not ideal, but I'll have to make do.

Answer (score 2):

On the same `PaintListener` you use to paint the coloured background, you have to calculate the position and draw the text.  Here's how we do it here:

```
public void paintControl( PaintEvent event ) {
    // Is the button enabled?
    if ( !isEnabled() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get button bounds.
    Button button = (Button)event.widget;
    int buttonWidth = button.getSize().x;
    int buttonHeight = button.getSize().y;

    // Get text bounds.
    int textWidth = event.gc.textExtent( getText() ).x;
    int textHeight = event.gc.textExtent( getText() ).y;

    // Calculate text coordinates.
    int textX = ( ( buttonWidth - textWidth ) / 2 );
    int textY = ( ( buttonHeight - textHeight ) / 2 );

    /*
     * If the mouse is clicked and is over the button, i.e. the button is 'down', the text must be
     * moved a bit down and left.
     * To control this, we add a MouseListener and a MouseMoveListener on our button.
     * On the MouseListener, we change the mouseDown flag on the mouseDown and mouseUp methods.
     * On the MouseMoveListener, we change the mouseOver flag on the mouseMove method.
     */
    if ( mouseDown && mouseOver ) {
        textX++;
        textY++;
    }

    // Draw the new text.
    event.gc.drawText( getText(), textX, textY );

    // If button has focus, draw the dotted border on it.
    if ( isFocusControl() ) {
        int[] dashes = { 1, 1 };
        evento.gc.setLineDash( dashes );
        evento.gc.drawRectangle( 3, 3, buttonWidth - 8, buttonHeight - 8 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out and let you know how it works out for us.

Comment: Hmm... Doesn't look like it works. This puts the text in the center of the button which is not alawys the case. In particular for check buttons and radio buttons. Have you been able to find the location to draw the text for radio and check buttons? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I never had to do that for checks and radios, but I think it is just a matter of proper calculation of the textX and textY coordinates.