# How to set a darker shade for SWT.PUSH button when it is toggled

Tags: java, swt

By default, if a SWT.PUSH button is selected (toggled), the button is lightly blue shaded. I want to make the shade a little darker, so it is more visible which buttons are toggled. Does anyone know how i could go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [`Control`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FControl.html) contains this section for the method `Control#setBackground(Color)`:

> Sets the receiver's background color to the color specified by the argument, or to the default system color for the control if the argument is null.
>
> Note: **This operation is a hint and may be overridden by the platform. For example, on Windows the background of a Button cannot be changed.**

---

However, you can "hijack" the painting event and paint whatever you want on your `Button`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747562/how-to-set-swt-button-foreground-color) is a related question to this topic.