# SWT - How to change color of text in buttons?

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to find a way to change the color of Text of a button in SWT but i got stuck. So i wonder if there is a way to change the color of the text of a button.

Comment: does `mybutton.setForeground(Color)` work?

Comment: The sad truth that it's not working

Comment: setForeground has no effect for Buttons as said here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4747621/1842957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows `setForeground` is not working.

You can add a `PaintListener`:

```
    Button myButton = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
    myButton.setText("Hello");
    myButton.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            e.gc.setForeground(color);

            e.gc.drawText("Hello", 6, 5, SWT.DRAW_TRANSPARENT);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, work like a charm. But it's feel that there is a white rectangle wrap the text, how can i remove that rectangle. Once more time, thank you very much

Comment: @ThànhĐàoNgọc Change `SWT.NONE` to `SWT.DRAW_TRANSPARENT`.